# Системные сообщения в андроиде

Tags: android-ndk, android, java, c, c++

Имеется большой проект на С++ под Андроид. Появилась интересная задача, как взаимодействовать с драйверами OC? По сути приложение будет работа в режиме пользователя, но ему необходимо подменить несколько драйверов, работающих в режиме ядра. Возможно ли такое в андроиде? Надо ли для этого использовать нативную активити или и из обычной джава активити можно?

Answer (score 1):

> подменить несколько драйверов

Думаю, что вы не можете подменять никакие драйвера в системе. Кроме того, все драйвера работают в пространстве ядра и линкуются динамически к ядру, либо залинкованы к нему статически. Во втором случае уж точно никак не подменить их. Но модули всегда нативные.

Comment: В обоих случаях создается новая прошивка. Думаю и без прошивки как-то можно, но как? Самая большая сложность - положить библиотеку в режим ядра, непонятен процесс. Про модули, в андроиде есть понятие активити, те пользовательский интерфейс. Возможность нативного GUI появилась только в 9 API (андроид 2.3).

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду модули ядра. 

Вы не можете менять модули ядра без новой прошивки или каких-то странных патчей. А что вы имеете в виду под подкладываение библиотеки в режим ядра? Библиотеку нельзя просто положить в режим ядра. Должен быть написан соответствующий модуль. Если, конечно, стандартный модуль действительно не умеет делать то, что от него требуется.

Comment: Я имею ввиду замену стандартной либы, например, библиотеки работы с bluetooth модулем, те у меня есть улучшенная версия данной либы, которая имеет больше профайлов, и я хочу ее заменить на свою.

Comment: Тогда режим ядра ни при чём. В таком случае, вам придётся делать прошивку: просто подсунуть свои либы не получится.

Comment: Практически все системные библиотеки работают в режиме ядра. При этом не хочется делать отдельную прошивку, хочется иметь апк пакет.